# Is there a way to add a custom Intellisense mode?

Tags: intellisense, mode, iar

In VisualStudio 2019 I can set different
[modes for IntelliSense](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cHjlG.png), where i specify what compiler and architecture I am using.

Is there a way to add a custom mode for another compiler (for example a mode for the IAR compiler), so Intellisense could understand code that was written for IAR ?

I would also be curious about what the modes actually do. Why does Intellisense need to know the compiler I am using ? Why does it need to know the architecture I am writing code for ?

It would be great if someone could demystify this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

IAR started offering their "Visual Studio Code" experience with open-source extensions: https://github.com/iarsystems/iar-vsc-build#readme

The IAR extension piggybacks the Microsoft VSCode's C/C++ IntelliSense extension and recognizes the IAR compiler's extended keywords (i.e., `__root`).